# laravel 7 slideshow gallery onclick option

Tags: javascript, php, slideshow, laravel-7

I am trying to create a slideshow image gallery by following this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_gallery

I am also using @foreach to get the images. So far, I have managed to get the images and the next/previous buttons are working fine. But I am not sure how to do the onClick part.

here is my code

**view/blade**

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($images as $image)
    <div class="mySlides">
        <img src="{{ asset($image->image_location) }}" style="width:100%" alt="slide">
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
</div>

<div class="row">
    @foreach ($images as $image)
    <div class="column">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="{{ asset($image->image_location) }}" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Image not Available">
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**script**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the onclick part". There are multiple onclick items, any particular problem?

Comment: what I need is when I click any thumbnail it should show the relevant larger image on the slider. As I am using  loop (foreach...) I am not sure how to code that 'onclick' part on view/blade.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the blade `@foreach` loop, a `$loop` variable is available, as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#the-loop-variable

You may use `$loop->index` to access the index of your thumbnail image in the array, and use that in the onclick event:

```js
onclick="currentSlide({{ $loop->index }})"
```

Comment: thanks Mr Maarten, your idea is right. it works now. Although I had to use onclick="currentSlide({{$loop->index+1}})".